# D3 stacked area chart with x-axis as Month names and also with Legends

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I’m trying to build D3 stacked area chart with x-axis as Month names but there are some errors as MNaN and also on D3 official site there is data loading for chart from a file (.csv. .json, .tsv, etc) but I want to load data from array.
Also tooltip (A \n Total(A) \n % of A) and legends are not visible.
I am referring this code for generating Stacked area chart : https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/stackedarea_template.html

Can anyone help me with the code, below is the data required

[image: Table Data]

[image: Required Graph]

Structure of array:

```js
var data = [
    {
        "Month": "Jan", "A": "372290.4", "B": "9609.42", "C": "5496.94", "D": "4478",
        "E": "508005.08", "F": "188776.25", "G": "6637.87", "H": "0", "I": "109.36", "J": "357361.55", "Total": "1452764.87"
    },
    {
        "Month": "Feb", "A": "739822.97", "B": "19218.84", "C": "12516.24", "D": "8956",
        "E": "1018268.66", "F": "377525.74", "G": "15948.5", "H": "23.46", "I": "969.92", "J": "714723.1", "Total": "2907973.43"
    },
    {
        "Month": "Mar", "A": "1108095.89", "B": "28828.26", "C": "22268.98", "D": "13434",
        "E": "1528299.3", "F": "565977.38", "G": "28712.76", "H": "1027.62", "I": "3067.22", "J": "1072084.65", "Total": "4371796.06"
    },
    {
        "Month": "Apr", "A": "1474738.92", "B": "38727.73", "C": "34389.72", "D": "17981.44",
        "E": "2071177.85", "F": "754827.43", "G": "45430.62", "H": "7307.35", "I": "7312.26", "J": "1429446.2", "Total": "5881339.52"
    },
    {
        "Month": "May", "A": "1834106.67", "B": "49394.68", "C": "52238.77", "D": "23057.93",
        "E": "2585714.03", "F": "931441.48", "G": "66322.02", "H": "20124.51", "I": "13769.13", "J": "1786807.75", "Total": "7362976.97"
    },
    {
        "Month": "Jun", "A": "2186201.94", "B": "65798.97", "C": "74773.06", "D": "31084",
        "E": "3085654.69", "F": "1108985.53", "G": "93788.5", "H": "33374.4", "I": "25559.3", "J": "2144169.3", "Total": "8849389.69"
    },
    {
        "Month": "July", "A": "2537665.76", "B": "87416.04", "C": "107505.33", "D": "40071.93",
        "E": "3561821.35", "F": "1286529.58", "G": "128477.84", "H": "46917.84", "I": "39826.26", "J": "2501530.85", "Total": "10337762.78"
    }
];
```

Comment: Do share the structure of your array. I can imagine two structures:
1. arrayOfArrays = [['Month', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], ['Jan', 37, 96, 54, 44, 50, 18], ...]
2 arrayOfObjects = [{Month: 'Jan', A: 37, ....}, {...}, ...]

The solution will vary a little bit based on your array structure.

Comment: Hi @Shreshth, I have updated my question with array structure.

Answer (score 0):

Reusing some code from the link you shared, but using the latest version of d3 (v7), I have shared the solution. Works for your array structure.

Implementing tooltips in d3 charts isn't very straightforward (not included in the attached code snippet). You can check these two examples for implementing tooltip (uses d3.bisect):

1. [With old d3 version (v3)](https://bl.ocks.org/fabiomainardi/3976176cb36e718a608f)
2. [With newer version, not latest (v5)](https://observablehq.com/@didoesdigital/24-may-2020-area-charts-in-d3-with-tooltips)

```js
const data = [
  {
    Month: 'Jan',
    A: '372290.4',
    B: '9609.42',
    C: '5496.94',
    D: '4478',
    E: '508005.08',
    F: '188776.25',
    G: '6637.87',
    H: '0',
    I: '109.36',
    J: '357361.55',
    Total: '1452764.87',
  },
  {
    Month: 'Feb',
    A: '739822.97',
    B: '19218.84',
    C: '12516.24',
    D: '8956',
    E: '1018268.66',
    F: '377525.74',
    G: '15948.5',
    H: '23.46',
    I: '969.92',
    J: '714723.1',
    Total: '2907973.43',
  },
  {
    Month: 'Mar',
    A: '1108095.89',
    B: '28828.26',
    C: '22268.98',
    D: '13434',
    E: '1528299.3',
    F: '565977.38',
    G: '28712.76',
    H: '1027.62',
    I: '3067.22',
    J: '1072084.65',
    Total: '4371796.06',
  },
  {
    Month: 'Apr',
    A: '1474738.92',
    B: '38727.73',
    C: '34389.72',
    D: '17981.44',
    E: '2071177.85',
    F: '754827.43',
    G: '45430.62',
    H: '7307.35',
    I: '7312.26',
    J: '1429446.2',
    Total: '5881339.52',
  },
  {
    Month: 'May',
    A: '1834106.67',
    B: '49394.68',
    C: '52238.77',
    D: '23057.93',
    E: '2585714.03',
    F: '931441.48',
    G: '66322.02',
    H: '20124.51',
    I: '13769.13',
    J: '1786807.75',
    Total: '7362976.97',
  },
  {
    Month: 'Jun',
    A: '2186201.94',
    B: '65798.97',
    C: '74773.06',
    D: '31084',
    E: '3085654.69',
    F: '1108985.53',
    G: '93788.5',
    H: '33374.4',
    I: '25559.3',
    J: '2144169.3',
    Total: '8849389.69',
  },
  {
    Month: 'July',
    A: '2537665.76',
    B: '87416.04',
    C: '107505.33',
    D: '40071.93',
    E: '3561821.35',
    F: '1286529.58',
    G: '128477.84',
    H: '46917.84',
    I: '39826.26',
    J: '2501530.85',
    Total: '10337762.78',
  },
]

const margin = { top: 60, right: 230, bottom: 50, left: 80 }
const width = 660 - margin.left - margin.right
const height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom

const svg = d3
  .select('#my_dataviz')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`)

const columns = Object.keys(data[0])

data.columns = columns
// List of groups = header of the csv files
const keys = data.columns.slice(1, -1)

const allValueColumns = data.columns.slice(1)

const yExtent = [0, 0]
const dataParsed = data.map(d => {
  const pd = { ...d }
  allValueColumns.forEach(col => {
    pd[col] = parseFloat(d[col])
    yExtent[0] = d3.min([pd[col], yExtent[0]])
    yExtent[1] = d3.max([pd[col], yExtent[1]])
  })
  return pd
})

// color palette
const color = d3.scaleOrdinal().domain(keys).range(d3.schemeSet2)

// stack the data
const stackedData = d3.stack().keys(keys)(dataParsed)

const xDomain = dataParsed.map(d => d.Month)
const x = d3.scalePoint().domain(xDomain).range([0, width])

const xAxis = svg
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${height})`)
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(5))

const y = d3.scaleLinear().domain(yExtent).range([height, 0])

const area = d3
  .area()
  .x(function (d) {
    return x(d.data.Month)
  })
  .y0(function (d) {
    return y(d[0])
  })
  .y1(function (d) {
    return y(d[1])
  })

svg
  .append('g')
  .selectAll('path')
  .data(stackedData)
  .enter()
  .append('path')
  .attr('class', function (d) {
    return `area ${d.key}`
  })
  .style('fill', function (d) {
    return color(d.key)
  })
  .attr('d', area)
  
  svg.append('g').call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(5))
```

```html
          <div id="my_dataviz" ></div>
          <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.1.1/d3.min.js" integrity="sha512-COTaPOlz12cG4fSfcBsxZsjauBAyldqp+8FQUM/dZHm+ts/jR4AFoJhCqxy8K10Jrf3pojfsbq7fAPTb1XaVkg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: Hi @Shreshth, I tried using your above code and it is working great. Thank you.
But for the tooltips I tried using the above two links you provided they also worked but the issue is I want tooltips on a particular area (i.e., A or B or C or ...) not on points.
I want tooltip to show label name, count and percentage of that area in graph if you can help.
For tooltip you can refer to this codepen link I tried but no luck https://codepen.io/hazdik/pen/RwbrLQK
This codepen link contains Donut chart which shows tooltip like I want.